# Uncaught exception on Doctrine 2.2 while insert a new entry in database

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

**i have a strange problem with Doctrine 2.2. I tried insert a new entry in database and i faced the following problem. What does it mean and how can i solve?**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class Model\User is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\DoctrineExplained\DoctrineORM\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php:147
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\DoctrineExplained\DoctrineORM\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver.php(166): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass('Model\User')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\DoctrineExplained\DoctrineORM\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(293): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass('Model\User', Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\DoctrineExplained\DoctrineORM\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(178): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('Model\User')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\DoctrineExplained\DoctrineORM\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(271): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMe in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\DoctrineExplained\DoctrineORM\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException.php on line 147
```

My project directory structure is like this :

**./test**

**DoctrineORM/**

**DoctrineORM/bin**

**DoctrineORM/bin/Doctrine**

**Model/**

**Model/User.php**

**test.php**

And lastly, those are my codes in **test.php** and **Model/User.php**

```
--- Model/User.php ---
<?php
//    Model File model/User.php 
namespace Model;

/** @Entity @Table(name="users") */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;


   /** @Column(type="string", length=50) */
    public $name;


  /** @Column(type="integer", length=50) */
    public $age;
}
?>
```

And the last codes are in the **test.php**

```
<?php
////    test.php


require 'DoctrineORM/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', 'DoctrineORM');
$classLoader->register(); 

$classloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('model', __DIR__);
$classloader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver('model');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setProxyDir('proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('proxies');

$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
$config->getAutoGenerateProxyClasses();

$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname' => 'test',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '0000'
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);



//    insert a new User to DB
$user = new model\User();
$user->name = 'lorem impum user';
$user->age = 55;
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Try running orm:validate-schema with the Doctrine 2 CLI tool - What is the output? Does it validate?

Comment: sorry i don't develop this on linux.(on windows) How can i execute on windows ?

Comment: Try following the instructions here: http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/07/28/setting-up-command-line-php-on-windows/  - After setting up the php command, you should be able to run the doctrine tool

Comment: ok, which command i have to use on there **http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even on Windows, case sensitivity is important.  Use 'Model' in place of 'model' in your code.

Add 'use Model/User;' to the top of you test code and then use '$user = new User()';  This will verify that your class loader stuff is working.

And do take the time (as Jani has suggested) to figure out how to run this stuff from the command line.  Your development will be much faster.